# Running 32-bit app on 64-bit Ubuntu with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: ubuntu, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32-bit app ncx32app that used to run on my ISP DreamHost. The needed libraries from the packages "libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++5:i386" were copied to /home/myname/lib directory. Also, a symlink was created:

```
ln -sf /lib/ld-2.15.so /home/myname/lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

So I could run the app like that:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myname/lib ./ncx32app
```

However, after upgrade of the OS my app stopped running with "No such file or directory" error.

I have the same app running on my machine at home. I checked:

```
ldd ncx32app
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf771a000)
    libstdc++.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.5 (0xf7632000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf75dd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf75c0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf740a000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf771b000)
```

I copied these libraries on my ISP in /home/myname/lib, but I still couldn't run it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. At my ISP OS is Ubuntu 14.04. On my home machine it's 16.04. Here's the info from my home machine:

```
ldd -r -v ncx32app
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7702000)
    libstdc++.so.5 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.5 (0xf761a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf75c5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf75a8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf73f2000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7703000)

    Version information:
    ./ncx32app:
        libstdc++.so.5 (GLIBCPP_3.2) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.5
        libstdc++.so.5 (CXXABI_1.2) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.5
        libm.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.5:
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6:
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1:
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.4) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.3) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
        ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Comment: What's the output from `ldd -r -v ncx32app`?  That should provide some more information.

Comment: I've just added it in the OP.

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like a 64-bit library.  FWIW, I've never had to do a soft-link to `/lib/ld.so...` when using LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Why are you adding that?

Comment: Yes, this is an old app compiled long time ago in 32-bit environment. And it used to work on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with the described workaround: 32-bit libraries copied to local directory, the soft-link to /lib/ld-2.15.so (because the app expects ld-linux.so.2) and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. BTW, this was done by a DreamHost tech support, not by me. Now they upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. and it doesn't work anymore. Because I have the same app running on my machine at home (16.04.) , I tried to copy the lib files. But it didn't work.

Comment: Does `/lib/ld-2.15.so` still exist on the new version of Ubuntu you're having the problems on?

Comment: BTW, I just checked: dpkg --print-foreign-architectures and I got: i386. So the ISP does have multiarch for 32-bit. So in principle I should be able to run 32-bit apps.

Comment: This is the lib directory when it used to work under Ubuntu 14.04:lrwxrwxrwx 1 myname pg878592 18 Oct 27  2011 libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myname pg878592 12 Feb 16  2016 libm.so.6 -> libm-2.15.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 myname pg878592 116232 Apr 15  2012 libgcc_s.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myname pg878592 12 Feb 16  2016 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.15.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myname pg878592 10 Feb 16  2016 ld-linux.so.2 -> ld-2.15.so

Answer (score 0):

To run 32-bit ELF binaries, install `lib32z1` package.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install lib32z1
$ dpkg -L libc6-i386 | grep -w ld 
/lib32/ld-2.31.so
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
/lib32/ld-linux.so.2
```

To run the 32-bit app, run:

```
/usr/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ./ncx32app
```